# Automate crop and straighten photos

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, crop

In Photoshop CC 2017 we have the option `File -> Automate -> Crop and Straighten Photos`. I have scanned multiple photos, so that in an image there are 3 photos. I need to use this feature of photoshop, and automate it on all the scanned images as there are many of them.

I know there is the option to record a script by I didn't succeed to automate it.

The actions should be like follows:

1. Open each image in the folder
2. Apply `Crop and Straighten Photos`
3. Save all cropped images in another folder as PNG with the option to have best quality

Could you help me create it ?

Comment: why not use lightroom for this? It's great at making the same adjustment to large batches of photos.